# Extract data from certain year from Google public dataset - chicago_taxi_trips

Tags: google-bigquery, timestamp, filtering

I am trying to extract data from Google public data set - [chicago_taxi_trips](https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?p=bigquery-public-data&d=chicago_taxi_trips&page=dataset), since the dataset is huge, I would like to only extract data from 2012 & 2018

I am using the query below to extract the columns I need but I can't extract it with the `WHERE Year = 2012 OR Year = 2018` I have created the columns `Year` with a sql function

```
SELECT trip_start_timestamp, 
EXTRACT(year FROM trip_start_timestamp) as Year, 
EXTRACT(month FROM trip_start_timestamp) as Month, 
EXTRACT(day FROM trip_start_timestamp) as Day,
EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM trip_start_timestamp) as Weekday,
EXTRACT(Week FROM trip_start_timestamp) as Week,
EXTRACT(hour FROM trip_start_timestamp) as Hour, trip_end_timestamp, trip_seconds, trip_miles, fare, tips, tolls, extras, 
trip_total, payment_type, company
FROM `bigquery-public-data.chicago_taxi_trips.taxi_trips`
WHERE Year = 2012 OR Year = 2018
```

**How should I change my code for it to work?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply replace

```
WHERE Year = 2012 OR Year = 2018
```

with

```
WHERE EXTRACT(year FROM trip_start_timestamp) IN (2012, 2018)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mikhail. A small follow up question, turns out there is still too many entries in each year, so I tried to ```LIMIT =10000``` for the query, but the monthly distribution of the data obtained is too uneven, is there a way to modify the search so I get 1000 entries for each month for year 2012 & 2018? Total 24000 rows.

Thank you again in advance for the help btw

Comment: sure. post new question and we will be happy to answer. meantime, please consider voting up the answer if it helped :o)

Comment: I figured that adding ```ORDER BY RAND()``` can help select a random sample

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
EXTRACT(year FROM trip_start_timestamp) as Year, 
EXTRACT(month FROM trip_start_timestamp) as Month, 
EXTRACT(day FROM trip_start_timestamp) as Day,
EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM trip_start_timestamp) as Weekday,
EXTRACT(Week FROM trip_start_timestamp) as Week,
EXTRACT(hour FROM trip_start_timestamp) as Hour, trip_end_timestamp, trip_seconds, trip_miles, fare, tips, tolls, extras, 
trip_total, payment_type, company
FROM `bigquery-public-data.chicago_taxi_trips.taxi_trips`
WHERE 
  (trip_start_timestamp >= TIMESTAMP("2012-01-01 00:00:00+00") AND trip_start_timestamp < TIMESTAMP("2013-01-01 00:00:00+00"))
  OR 
  (trip_start_timestamp >= TIMESTAMP("2018-01-01 00:00:00+00") AND trip_start_timestamp < TIMESTAMP("2019-01-01 00:00:00+00"))
```